# Add values from a list of dictionaries to separate lists and find/count common values

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list containing dictionaries like this:

```
[{"abc":"da123-tap","efg":"xyzf","acd":"123-brf"}, {"abc":"ab234-tap","efg":"yuvi","acd":"345-brf"}]
```

I want all the values of `abc` in a list (`list1`) and all the values of `efg` in another list (`list2`).

**Update to question:**

I read a file to get this list of dictionaries:

```
[{"Sample":"da123-tap","Name":"john","dof":"Date(304239600000)","Account":"Clinic1"},
{"Sample":"da456-tap-tap","Name":"smith","dof":"Date(304239600000)","Account":"Clinic2"},
{"Sample":"da678-tap-tap","Name":"jane","dof":"Date(304239600000)","Account":"Clinic1"},
{"Sample":"da987-tap-tap","Name":"doe","dof":"Date(304239600000)","Account":"Clinic2"}]
```

Find:

1. Values from `Sample` in `list1`
2. Values from `Account` in `list2`
3. Count values of `Sample` that belong to `Clinic1`
4. Count values of `Sample` that belong to `Clinic2`

Comment: Ok, what have you done so far?

Comment: Thanks for telling us?

Answer (score 0):

Only for educational reasons, the elegant way to direct values of different keys into multiple lists could be to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and unpacking:

```
>>> l = [
...     {"abc":"da123-tap","efg":"xyzf","acd":"123-brf"}, 
...     {"abc":"ab234-tap","efg":"yuvi","acd":"345-brf"}
... ]
>>> 
>>> a, b = zip(*[(item["abc"], item["efg"]) for item in l])
>>> print(a)
('da123-tap', 'ab234-tap')
>>> print(b)
('xyzf', 'yuvi')
```